# Git merge conflict when trying to pull from subtree

Tags: git, git-merge, git-subtree

After doing a git pull I'm getting a bunch of conflicts across ~100 files. I want the recently pulled changes to overwrite my own code.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21434346/773263) which seems similar to what I'm trying to do. But when I use:

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs
```

It results in:

> Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.

I can run mergetool and go through each file individually but I already know I want to favor the new changes for everything.

I try to discard the merge and pull again with the following:

```
git merge --abort

git subtree pull --prefix=interactives/d2l/ https://mygiturl.com master --squash
```

But everytime I pull I get the conflict.

Comment: Why not simply discard your commits then?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I shouldn't have any may be related to me using subtree so I updated question.

Answer (score 1):

the message means that you already have leftovers from previous merge attempt. You should reset it by calling `git merge --abort` and try whatever you planned to do