# git: resolve merge conflicts by accepting my changes

Tags: git, merge

I have a bunch of files that I have deleted in `develop`, and those files have been modified in `master`.  I want to merge `master` into `develop`, but I am getting a merge conflict, since both branches have modified the same file.

How do I merge `master` into `develop`, and accept all changes present in `develop`?  I tried `git merge -s recursive -X ours master`, per [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433988/resolve-git-merge-conflict-using-all-my-changes-discarding-theirs), but I still got a bunch of conflicts.  I tried `git merge -s ours master`, but I got an empty commit.

Comment: To clarify: you want `master` and `develop` to end up the same, with all `master` changes dropped and all `develop` changes accepted?

Comment: @PaulHicks no. I want `master` to retain all of its changes, and `develop` to merge in all files from `master` that do not conflict with changes in `develop`, and discard changes from `master` that do.

Comment: there were conflicts between `master` and `develop`, yes.  there were about 10 files that had been modified by `master` and not touched by `develop`, but there were 18 files that were modified in `master` and deleted in `develop`.  I had a clean working directory with no local changes

Comment: Ah.. a delete will conflict with a change, even with `-X ours`. You will have to merge those manually. It's as simple as `git rm`ing the files, then re-running the merge command to accept the deletions.

Comment: Don't follow. They were already `git rm`ed. And those deletions had already been committed to `develop`.

Comment: Actually, since they're already `git rm`ed in develop, you want to simply `rm` them during the merge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git merge strategy 'theirs' is not resolving modify/delete conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254037/git-merge-strategy-theirs-is-not-resolving-modify-delete-conflict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as some quick background, when you run `git merge otherbranch`:

- Git examines the commit graph, which generally looks like this only more complicated:

  ```
  ...--o--B--o--o--L   <-- yourbranch
           \
            o--o--o--R   <-- otherbranch
  ```

  I have labeled three specific commits here, *B* which is the *merge base*, *L* which is the left-side or local or `--ours` commit, and *R* which is the right-side or remote or `--theirs` commit.
- Git then runs two `git diff` commands, more or less, as with:

  ```
  git diff --find-renames B L > /tmp/diff.B-to-L
  git diff --find-renames B R > /tmp/diff.B-to-R
  ```
- The merge process itself then consists of picking up *one copy* of each of the changes in these two diffs.  For a file that's modified only in B-to-L or only in B-to-R, that's really easy: Git can just take the L or R version of that file.  For a file that's not modified at all, Git can take the B, L, or R version of the file, as there's no difference between any of them.  It's only files that have been changed somehow in both L and R, with respect to B, that require hard work (a "low level" merge).

The biggest problem, though, comes about when you have a situation like yours: the file is *modified* on one side, but *removed entirely* on the other side.  It's not clear to Git whether to resolve this by taking the individual line changes, or removing the file entirely.  (You get the same kind of conflict if a file is renamed in both B-to-L and B-to-R, but to two different names; or if a new file is added in both B-to-L and B-to-R, but with the *same* name.)

I call these *high level* conflicts, and Git will not resolve them, not even with `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs`.  For conflicts within a single file—which I call *low level* conflicts, where some `file.ext` has changes on both sides that overlap—Git will normally stop with a conflict, but with the eXtended options `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs`, Git will favor the "ours" or "theirs" change for that particular conflict.

With high level conflicts, however, you must resolve them yourself.  If the correct resolution is to remove the file, run `git rm <filename>`.  If the correct resolution is to keep the modified file, run `git add <filename>`.  If the correct resolution is something else, do the something else, then `git add` the resulting file(s).  Note that these `git add` and/or `git rm` operations work on the index, copying files from the current work-tree.  Conflicted files are represented by extra index entries; these extra entries are cleaned up and put away when you `git add` or `git rm`.

Once all high and low level conflicts are resolved and all the resolutions have been `git add`ed (or `git rm`ed if appropriate), running `git commit` will finish the merge.  This commit takes whatever is in the index at this point.

Comment: so it isn't possible to tell git that, for all conflicts, I want our changes?

Comment: Only for "low level" (within-file) conflicts. One might think `-X` arguments should apply to high level conflicts too, and perhaps they *should*, but the code happens to be written to just pass `-X whatever` on to the low level merge program. If there is a high level conflict, the low level program never runs in the first place!

Comment: is there some way to implement this ability? a custom merge strategy or something?  or am I just SOL?

Comment: If you write your own merge *strategy*, yes: you take over the entire job of merging. You find the merge base(s); you compute any diffs you care to find; you compute the result; and you make the final commit. Just place a program named `git-merge-foo` in your `$PATH` and run `git merge -s foo`; your program will be invoked, and can (and must!) do the whole job at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a merge tool. Here is one example:

git mergetool --tool emerge

commands:

a- choose change in A

b- choose change in B

n- next change

p- previous change

q- finish merge

[info on emerge](http://www.nongnu.org/emacsdoc-fr/manuel/emerge.html)

In the future I would only merge into master. have a Master and Develop branch, then branch off of develop, when you want to update master, merge develop into master. Then continue on in that fashion.